# Can not SSH into my google-computer-engine instance

Tags: google-compute-engine

When I use google cloud shell it accepts my user/pass but then I get disconnected
From the serial log it looks like this

Aug 15 05:30:32 instance-num1 sshd[6861]: Accepted password for USERNAME from 34.74.161.184 port 38912 ssh2
A
Aug 15 05:30:32 instance-num1 sshd[6863]: Received disconnect from 34.74.161.184: 11: disconnected by user

Even when I use PUTTY the same thing happens.

I've tried Google Cloud Shell
I've tried PUTTY
I've tried SSH in browser as well

Comment: By default, Google Compute Engine instances do not accept password-based logins. If you configured something else, edit your post with details. Also show the command you are using, etc.

Comment: Only reason I'm trying to use password based login cause the "SSH-in-browser" doesnt work at the moment.  When I use the SSH-In-Browser I get the following error   "SSH authentication has failed".  Tells me to look at the auth file.  In that file is says "shd[23022]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user USERNAME by (uid=0)"   So I'm very lost.